# Comparing string encrypted or not?

Tags: php, string, oracle, encryption

I need to check if there are some modification on my database(oracle),

To prevent a check `column by column` or `char by char` i think its better to encrypt all columns concatenated and compare the encrypted string instead of all chars.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Is that method better than compare with the normal string?

Comment: What about a simple "last updated" column?

Comment: You mean create this column or oracle have something like that native? I can't modify the database =/ its a external one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is intensive. You are more interested in a hash (MD5, SHA, etc) because what you want is a statistically very slim chance of having the same thing post function after a change as before it.

However, there is a flaw with just concat'ing all columns.

Suppose I have A column with 'bob' and B column with 'tom' and I concat and hash them for .
If the row is later changed to 'bo' in A and 'btom' in B, the concat and hash will give the same answer despite being different.

Truthfully, comparing column by column is the best case for a simple table. But if you want to reduce the amount of data to compare to a minimum and you have long rows (or LOBs for example), here is a process that may help:

1. Hash each column. Concat the results. The results of each Hash will be a specific length and you will avoid the problem above.
2. Hash the combined results. This will give you a single string you can compare the next time you need to check the row.

Comment: Very googd, it's exactly what i want.